# VS2022 Cant Refererence code behind correctly using Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create a custom component that will be used on multiple pages.

I created a new Blazor component and for now just did a simple :

```
<div class="outer">
    <span>@title</span>
</div>
```

with an @code block in the page. just setting the title and was fine. I then highlighted the code block, right mouse clicked and let VS move my code block into partial Class.

now i receive @title does not exist in the current context on the page.

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Restart VS, Rebuild the project. If the problem  persists then post the code behind here, as well as the project structure (file and folder names)

Comment: And check your new file is not excluded in the .csproj file.

Comment: A restart seemed to do it....Thanks all.